# Trying to call a javascript function on a button click but nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change colour of each colour block given in picture with a click in javascript. When I click nothing is happening

[image]

My code is given below. I am new to JS. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Spectrum Project</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="spectrum.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Spectrum</h2>
            <table class="spectrum">
                <tr>
                    <td id="one"></td>
                    <td id="two"></td>
                    <td id="three"></td>
                    <td id="four"></td>
                    <td id="five"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <button onclick="myFunc" id="button1">Click to see magic</button>
            <script src="spectrum.js"></Script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```js
    function myFunc(){
        document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundcolor = "yellow";
        document.getElementById("three").style.backgroundcolor = "orange";
        document.getElementById("four").style.backgroundcolor = "pink";
        document.getElementById("five").style.backgroundcolor = "black";
      }
```

Comment: `onclick="myFunc"` is not executing the function

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this: I added parenthesis to execute the function and also text inside the table so it becomes more visible.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spectrum Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="spectrum.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Spectrum</h2>
        <table class="spectrum">
            <tr>
                <td id="one">one</td>
                <td id="two">two</td>
                <td id="three">three</td>
                <td id="four">four</td>
                <td id="five">five</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        <button onclick="myFunc()" id="button1">Click to see magic</button>
        <script src="spectrum.js"></Script>
    </body>
</html>
```

'''
'''

```
function myFunc(){
    document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundcolor = "yellow";
    document.getElementById("three").style.backgroundcolor = "orange";
    document.getElementById("four").style.backgroundcolor = "pink";
    document.getElementById("five").style.backgroundcolor = "black";
  }
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve it, as demonstrated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). 
The simplest fix is to add parenthesis to the onclick function to make it work.

`<button onclick="myFunc()">`

Moreover, you can generalize the color change function to something like:

```
function changeColor(id, color) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundcolor = color
}
function myFunc() {
   changeColor("one", "red")
   changeColor("two", "blue")
}
```

To make it even less repetitive, check out the `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` methods.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Using `getComputedStyle` you can get backgroundColor of box and after apply to body.

```js
var colors = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
colors.forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener('click',function(a){
    var currentColor = getComputedStyle(a.target)["background-color"];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = currentColor;
  })
});
```

```css
container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.box{
  width:10rem;
  height:20rem;
  background:grey;
  margin:.5rem;
  border:1px solid white
}

.pink{
  background:fuchsia
}

.red{
  background:red
}

.violet{
  background:darkviolet
}

.yellow{
  background:yellow
}

.orange{
  background:orange
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div class="box pink"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box violet"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>
  <div class="box orange"></div>
</container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the new angle to this.